# Why does enabling server side prepared statements result in CONCUR_UPDATABLE error?

Tags: mysql, jdbc, concurrency, prepared-statement, resultset

When I enable server-side prepared statments via `useServerPrepStmts` jdbc flag, result set update operations fail *after* the first request for a given query with:

> Result Set not updatable.This result set must come from a statement
>   that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE,
>   the query must select only one table, can not use functions and must
>   select all primary keys from that table

When I disable server-side prepared statements, result set update operations work flawlessly.

Since the query involves only 1 table, has a primary key, returns a single row, and no functions are involved, what must be happening is that the prepared statement is created with ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY and then cached server-side. Subsequent requests for the same query will draw the prepared statement from the cache and then, even though the client sends `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` for `rs.updateRow()`, concurrency is still set to `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` on the server.

If I am correct in above assumption, how does one override the server-side cache in this case? (everything else is fine with prepared statement caching, just result set row operations are affected).

Linux (CentOS 5.7) with:

> mysql-connector-java 5.1.33
>
> mysql 5.6.20

**EDIT**

not relevant <s>I notice that the first query, which always succeeds, has this in the query log: `SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=1`, and all subsequent queries fail with this: `SET SQL_SELECT_LIMIT=DEFAULT`. Not sure if this is the cause of the problem, or just a side effect. Guess I'll try to manually `setFetchSize` on the client and see if that makes a difference...</s>

Comment: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-dont-use-query-cache/ SQL_NO_CACHE

Comment: @DavidSoussan interesting, thanks. Would be nice to know how to sort the problem out with caching enabled though.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround is to append `FOR UPDATE` to `ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY` select statement on the client with `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE` concurrency for the new prepared statement. This allows for server statement caching while still being able to modify a JDBC `ResultSet`.

Side note: 
the `select ... for update` statement itself does not appear to be eligible for caching; i.e. query log shows `Prepare` and `Execute` lines on every request.